# If as assert fails, is there a bug?

Tags: debugging, assert

I've always followed the logic: if assert fails, then there is a bug.  Root cause could either be:

- Assert itself is invalid  (bug)
- There is a programming error   (bug)
- (no other options)

I.E. Are there any other conclusions one could come to?  Are there cases where an assert would fail and there is no bug?

Comment: You have 1,337 reputation. That's leet.

Comment: Now somebody went and ruined it! (I still have a screenshot of when I hit 1337 rep :p)

Comment: One thing I've seen a lot of is asserting that some input state is "valid," e.g. the file that's being read has the right header.  This is a "bad" assert though, as it's expected if the file is bogus, but the file isn't under programming control.  It's like asserting that the user presses the enter key instead of the spacebar.  Report the error, but don't use an assert.

Comment: Too leet, already off that number.  Quick neg him back down!  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a bug in the code.

*[Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)*

> Assertions check for conditions that
>   should never occur. [...]
>
> If an
>   assertion is fired for an anomalous
>   condition, the corrective action is
>   not merely to handle an error
>   gracefully- the corrective action is
>   to change the program's source code,
>   recompile, and release a new version
>   of the software.
>
> A good way to
>   think of assertions is as executable
>   documentation - you can't rely on them
>   to make the code work, but they can
>   document assumptions more actively
>   than program-language comments can.

Answer (score 6):

If assert fails there is a bug in either the caller or callee. Why else would there be an assertion?

Comment: Why else?  I don't know, that's why I asked.  I regularly file bugs against developers for assert pops that they claim are "by design".  Just wanted to make sure they are wrong / I'm on the same page as the s/w world :)

Comment: Well if it's expected to fail, it doesn't really meet the requirement for an assertion.  When you say, "I assert that this is true," you're not saying it's sometimes or usually true, you're saying that it's *always* true.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. An assertation is an expectation. `assert(x == 5)` means, "I think x will be 5 here". However, it is somewhat abused in low level code, for example, some people say you _must_ only use the API a certain way or _undefined behaviour_ will result, and then sometimes they stick in assertions to enforce checking against invalid input anyways, which just issues a warning or exits the program. This is bordering on stupidity but anything other than this defeats the purpose of an assertion.

Answer (score 3):

That's a good question.

My feeling is, if the assert fails due to your code, then it is a bug. The assertion is an expected behaviour/result of your code, so an assertion failure will be a failure of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Only if the assert was meant to show a warning condition - in which case a special class of assert should have been used.

So, any assert should show a bug as you suggest.

Comment: Using assertions as warnings is an error and indicates a misunderstanding of what the word "assert" means.

Comment: We have some special case debug code that throws a message up similiar to an assert, but allows execution to continue.  It's called assertWarn().  More serious than a printf/log, but not worthy of a stop.  I'm curious what others would call this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using assertions you're following [Bertrand Meyer's Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) philosophy.  It's a programming error - the contract (assertion) you have specified is not being followed by the client (caller).

Comment: Of course, the contract may not be the correct one.  I've done that before.  However, either the contract or the client is buggy.

Comment: Actually no.  The assertion is stated by the contract.  If the client doesn't conform, then that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to be logically inclusive about all the possibilities, remember that electronic circuitry is known to be affected by radiation from space.  If the right photon/particle hits in just the right place at just the right time, it can cause an otherwise logically impossible state transition.

The probability is vanishingly small but still non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one case that wouldn't really class as a bug:

An assert placed to check for something external that normally should be there.  You're hunting something nutty that occurs on one machine and you want to know if a certain factor is responsible.

A real world example (although from before the era of asserts):  If a certain directory was hidden on a certain machine the program would barf.  I never found any piece of code that should have cared if the directory was hidden.  I had only very limited access to the offending machine (it had a bunch of accounting stuff on it) so I couldn't hunt it properly on the machine and I couldn't reproduce it elsewhere.  Something that was done with that machine (the culprit was never identified) occasionally turned that directory hidden.

I finally resorted to putting a test in the startup to see if the directory was hidden and stopping with an error if it was.

Answer (score 0):

No. An assertion failure means something happened that the original programmer did not intend or expect to occur.

This can indicate:

- A bug in your code (you are simply calling the method incorrectly)
- A bug in the Assertion (the original programmer has been too zealous and is complaining about you doing something that is quite reasonable and the method will actually handle perfectly well.
- A bug in the called code (a design flaw). That is, the called code provides a contract that does not allow you to do what you need to do. The assertion warns you that you can't do things that way, but the solution is to extend the called method to handle your input.
- A known but unimplemented feature. Imagine I implement a method that could process positive and negative integers, but I only need it (for now) to handle positive ones. I know that the "perfect" implementation would handle both, but until I actually *need* it to handle negatives, it is a waste of effort to implement support (and it would add code bloat and possibly slow down my application). So I have considered the case but I decide not to implement it until the need is proven. I therefore add an assert to mark this unimplemented code. When I later trigger the assert by passing a negative value in, I know that the additional functionality is now needed, so I must augment the implementation. Deferring writing the code until it is actually required thus saves me a lot of time (in most cases I never imeplement the additiona feature), but the assert makes sure that I don't get any bugs when I try to use the unimplemented feature.